# How to use the built-in round() function

Tags: python

I am trying to solve `?` in the expression below:

```
round(5.18, ?)
```

The result should be `10.0`.

I have thought of `round(5.18, print(10.0))`, but that isn't it because that gives:

```
10.0
5
```

Comment: It's not possible to round `5.18` to `10.0`, their distance is too much! If it is `9.5 - 9.9` now, it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> answer should be 10.0

```
>>> round(5.8, -1)
10.0
```

Comment: thank you! JUST came to that conclusion in my other monitor at the same time.  :)

Comment: :o interesting, but why tho?

Comment: @Copperfield As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round): `Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point...  Any integer value is valid for ndigits (positive, zero, or negative).`

Comment: yeah I read the doc too, still doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: I think I understand it now, is like diving it by 10 first, round it and multiplying it 10 again

Answer (score 0):

So the python help says:

```
Help on built-in function round in module builtins:

round(number, ndigits=None)
    Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits.
    
    The return value is an integer if ndigits is omitted or None.  Otherwise
    the return value has the same type as the number.  ndigits may be negative.
```

So, set ndigits to -1 digit after the comma

```
>>> round(5.8, -1)
10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write it as follows: `round(5.8, -1)`

and check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for more about the built-in round function.